# I want to change the value of 5 when Refresh button is clicked with useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

[image]
i know i did somthing wrong, but idk what XD,, help please

Comment: What are u trying to achieve? And its always better to post the code and not the screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using setrefClick incorrectly, it should be like this:

```
function refreshClick() {
   // This will put 8 into refClick
   setrefClick(8);
}
```

Comment: Thank you !, im new to react im doing my best :-)

Comment: You're welcome! Go get em!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are doing states wrong.</strike>

You are doing it just fine.

In order to initialize state you should follow this syntax

```js
const [state, stateUpdate] = useState(initialValue);
```

Upon observing your code, you can potentially change your state initialization to a proper way like this.

```js
const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("Customers");
const [customersCount, setCustomersCount] = useState(5);
```

And modify the customersCount like this:

```js
setCustomersCount(5);
```

Edit:

This is just a suggestion, however you can change the customerCount using

```js
setrefClick(8);
```